Importaciones con python
Estoy teniendo un problema con las importaciones de python. Tengo la siguiente estructura en el directorio de mi proyecto:
carpetaPrincipal
 |------carpeta1 
         |----- archivo1.py 
         |----- archivo2.py
         |----- __init__.py
 |--------carpeta2
            |-----archivo3.py
            |----- __init__.py
 |-------main.py
 |----- __init__.py

En main.py uso una funcion de archivo1 que usa una funcion de archivo2. Cuando ejecuto en archivo1 no hay problema y funciona como deberia. Cuando ejecuto en main me dice que no hay un modulo llamado archivo2.

Si tenemos por ejemplo:
carpeta1/archivo1.py
from archivo2 import bar

def foo():
    bar()

carpeta1/archivo2.py
def bar():
    print("Hola")

main.py.py
from carpeta1.archivo1 import foo

Podrás efectivamente ejecutar archivo1.py sin problemas desde carpeta1, pero si intentas ejecutar main.py tendrás un bonito:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'archivo2'

Esto ocurre porque el punto de entrada es este caso main.py y el intérprete añade a sys.path (rutas a usar en la búsqueda de módulos) el directorio de éste como primera entrada, es decir, la ruta a carpetaPrincipal. Cuando el intérprete se encuentra con from archivo2 import bar y se va buscarlo en en los directorios de sys.path no encuentra ni rastro de archivo2.
Para que tu import funcione adecuadamente debes tener en cuenta esto y establecer el import de acuerdo al punto de entrada de tu proyecto. En este caso debería ser:
carpeta1/archivo1.py
from carpeta1.archivo2 import bar

def foo():
    bar()

o también puedes usar un import relativo:
carpeta1/archivo1.py
from .archivo2 import bar

def foo():
    bar()

Si estás importando el módulo completo entonces simplemente sería from carpeta1 import archivo2 / impor carpeta1.archivo2 para el import absoluto o from . import archivo2 si usas el relativo.

Imports absolutos vs relativos
Tradicionalmente se ha preferido el uso de imports absolutos sobre los relativos, la principal razón es que son más legibles. Históricamente había otras razones que en Python moderno han dejado de ser válidos y que no merece comentar aquí.
Una de las principales ventajas de los imports relativos es que facilitan modificar la estructura del paquete o los nombres de módulos/subpaquetes sin tener que modificar los imports.
Eso si, ten en cuenta que solo se pueden usar imports relativos dentro de paquetes. Esto implica que no puedes ejecutar un módulo que los use directamente como script sin más. Es decir, en nuestro ejemplo, si archivo1.py usa un import relativo, hacer ésto:
$ cd carpetaPrincipal/carpeta1
$ python archivo1.py

generará una excepción:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Usa el tipo de imports que prefieras, eso si, intenta ser consistente en todo el proyecto.

Algunas observaciones
Python sigue un sistema modular y está desacoplado del sistema de archivos. Muchos de los problemas y luchas con el sistema de importación es fruto de no comprender ésto e intentar razonar todo como si se tratara simplemente de trabajar con rutas de archivos en un sistema de archivos, otras tantas vienen ocasionadas por estructurar mal los proyectos.

En la resolución de los imports de un paquete lo determinante es el punto de entrada al mismo, que es lo que determina la raiz en sys.path y por tanto el nombre a usar a la hora de importar. Cuando tu punto de entrada es main.py el nombre del módulo archivo2.py que el intérprete genera (atributo __name__) es carpeta1.archivo2.

La interacción con tu proyecto debería hacerse siempre desde un punto de entrada determinado, generalmente situado en la raiz del mismo, como es tu main.py. También puede que tu proyecto sea destinado a ser un paquete que será usado importandolo, con lo que tus imports necesitaran adaptarse ya que se resolveran a partir de un nivel más, desde carpetaPricipal y no desde main.py.

Ejecutar directamente módulos internos del paquete, subpaquetes o módulos de éstos es generalmente un antipatrón de diseño. Es decir, no deberías ejecutar directamente archivo1.py como script por ejemplo.


Los dos últimos puntos tiene relación con un problema al que casi todos se terminan enfrentando, intentar importar un archivo o subpaquete situado por encima en la jerarquía de archivos. Imagina que en tu ejemplo quieres importar una función de archivo3.py desde archivo1.py, si tu punto de entrada es tu main.py lo anterior es trivial, en archivo1.py haces:
from carpeta2.archivo3 import funcion

El problema aparece cuando se intenta ejecutar archivo1.py directamente. En este caso la ruta agregada a sys.path es carpeta1 y es imposible acceder a nada por encima de ella, ni con imports absolutos ni relativos.
¿Hay formas de hacerlo? Pues sí, principalmente dos:

Modificar sys.path manualmente, por ejemplo agregando carpeta3 o carpetaPrincipal al mismo antes de proceder a importar archivo3.py.

Ejecutar el módulo como script usando la opción -m del intérprete, con tu CWD en carpetaPrincipal:
$ python -m carpetaPrincipal.carpeta1.archivo1


Esto puede ser útil o incluso necesario en algunos casos concretos. Por ejemplo, típicamente durante el desarrollo del proyecto para realizar tests y depuración rápidamente del subpaquete. Por lo general, si necesitas usar "trucos" de este tipo con tu proyecto listo para producción, posiblemente tengas un problema de diseño y no de imports.

En definitiva, si tu proyecto está pensado para ejecutarse desde main.py ejecútalo siempre desde main.py. Si eventualmente necesitas ejecutar un sub-módulo como principal usa python -m desde carpetaPrincipal, te permitirá su ejecución como script principal sin tener que tocar los imports o alterar sys.path.

Probe la primera solucion y me sigue dando el mismo error. Cuando uso imports relativos me dice 'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'

@rocioog00 he editado la respuesta extendiendome un poco más en algunos conceptos.  Si no te aclaras comenta o mejor edita la pregunta (dejando lo que ya tienes intacto para no perder el contexto) y agrega el contendido de los archivos (o al menos un [mcve] que se pueda ejecutar y genere el mismo error que en tu proyecto real) y muy importante desde dónde y cómo los estás intentando ejecutar.
